# Spring MVC: Performs a merge of session data after posting

Tags: spring-mvc

We are seeing a problem/feature with Spring MVC, in that an entry that is deleted in our client-side JSP re-appears when our request reaches the controller.

The following is a snippet of our GET request in the controller:

```
AssignmentRulesFormDTO assignmentRulesFormDTO = ...
    model.addAttribute("assignmentRulesForm", assignmentRulesFormDTO);
    return new ModelAndView(getPageName(), model);
```

So our AssignmentRulesFormDTO contains a number of Rule objects, and on our client-side one of these objects is deleted.
I have confirmed via Fiddler that the deleted object is not passed up to the server.
However, when it reaches our controller's save method the object has re-appeared.
This is the method signature of the save method:

```
public ModelAndView saveRuleAttributesAndRules(@ModelAttribute("assignmentRulesForm")
AssignmentRulesFormDTO assignmentRulesForm, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpSession session, Principal principal,
    ModelMap model) {
```

So it seems as if Spring is performing some sort of merge before it hits our controller.

Therefore, I am wondering what this phenomenon is called, and how to turn it off for this particular session attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Controller was annotated with `@SessionAttributes` which seemed to cause the problem. Therefore, once I removed this annotation a brand new AssignmentRulesFormDTO was created on submitting a save operation. `@SessionAttributes` seemed to be amalagamating the data added in the request to an existing a session attribute, hence the problem above

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the second snippet is a `@RequestMapping` method, I don't think you want to tag the `AssignmentRulesFormDTO` with a `@ModelAttributes` annotation. By using this annotation on the method parameter, [you are telling Spring to go and instantiate the `AssignmentRulesFormDTO` by executing the method annotated](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args) with `@ModelAttribute("assignmentRulesForm")`.

So what Spring does when dispatching to your `@RequestMapping` method to handle the `POST` is:

1. Find the appropriate `@RequestMapping` method
2. Examine each of the method parameters to see if the required data is there
3. If a `@ModelAttribute` parameter is found and that attribute does not already exist in the model, then find the method in the controller that populates that `@ModelAttribute`
4. Execute the method found in 3
5. Finally execute the `@RequestMapping` method

So it sounds like you should not annotated the parameter with `@ModelAttribute` if your goal is to have the `AssignmentRulesFormDTO` populated with the request body *only*. Instead, you probably want [to use `@RequestBody`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody).

Comment: There is no method annotated with @ModelAttribute apart from the saveRuleAttributesAndRules listed above. I discovered a solution and will post the answer